# Can't SSH in using IP but can SSH using domain

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I’m using bash shell and attempting to login to an Ubuntu box

```
Host remote.web.domain
  Hostname 25.10.25.10
  User remote user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

When I try and SSH to the machine using an IP address, I get this error

```
$ ssh 25.10.25.10
myusername@25.10.25.10: Permission denied (publickey).
```

But oddly if I SSH using the domain name, I’m able to get in just fine

```
$ ssh remote.web.domain
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-149-generic x86_64)
```

What do I need to do, either server or client side, to allow SSH login using the IP address?

Answer (score 4):

On the config file, `Host remote.web.domain` indicates that the following lines only applies to remote.web.domain (probably not 25.10.25.10), then key parameters are different : myusername in the first attempt, and user in the second.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I change/configure things so that I can ssh using the IP address?

Comment: Copy the whole configuration, and the second time use `Host 25.10.25.10` instead.

Comment: You can use a single `Host` block listing both the IP and the hostname: `Host remote.web.domain 25.10.25.10...`

Comment: or just `ssh user@25.10.25.10`

Comment: @Kenster, thanks, that worked!